# Access ASMX Script Service via HTTP GET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asmx

I have made a ASP.net Web Service which contains a service which takes no parameters. I would like to invoke the ASMX service directly from a URL query.

This is my service

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public DataSet getXMLData()
{
    string strQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Products";
    string strRootNode = "Root";
    string strItemNode = "Item";

    dbConn = dbConnString;
    dbQuery = strQuery;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    da.Fill(ds, strItemNode);
    return ds;
}
```

This doesn't work

http://localhost:23147/ProductsWS.asmx?op=getXMLData

The page debug page for the service is displayed but it isn't invoked. I would like to be automatically invoked such that the query returns:

```
<Root xmlns="">
    <Item diffgr:id="Item1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ModelName>Tree</ModelName> 
        <UnitCost>7.0000</UnitCost> 
    </Item>
    <Item diffgr:id="Item2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <ModelName>Stump</ModelName> 
        <UnitCost>13.0200</UnitCost> 
    </Item>
</Root>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: First of all, which version of .NET are you using? If you're using .NET 3.0 or above, then you should not be creating ASMX web services at all. You should be using WCF instead. Second of all, please be more clear about what you're asking. What do you mean "passing one (1) URL"? What do you mean by "the xml file for the service"? Do you mean the WSDL?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Post updated to clarify

Comment: You haven't answered my questions. What are you trying to accomplish? Can you post the code of the services?

Comment: Sry. Further clarified. Using .Net 4.0

Comment: What happens if you just display the help page, then click on the `getXmlData` operation and submit it? Does it work? If so, then the URL it uses is the URL you need to use for the service. Also,  you haven't said what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: If I display the help page, then click on the getXmlData operation and submit it, it displays correctly. Using that URL directly gives the error                                        **Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getAllDataXML'.**       'doesn't work' means: The debug page for the service is displayed but it isn't invoked.

Comment: When you say, "using that URL directly", I presume you mean pasting it into a browser? I think you should run [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) while clicking the link in the help page. I believe you'll find that the help page does a POST. When you put the URL into the browser, that's a GET.

Comment: You are quite rite. Thanks for all your assistance. Have been able to get it to work. Used an Android emulator to pass the url and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is the URL for calling your service:

```
http://localhost:23147/ProductsWS.asmx/getXMLData
```

Comment: Good catch. I didn't even notice he was using the wrong operation name.